# .pem certificate into readable format

Tags: format, certificate, pem

What is the readable format of a certificate called? Is it ASN.1 format? 
I need the .pem certificate in a format where I can read the organization the date and so on.

And how can I convert the .pem file into this readable format in nodeJS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASN.1 is not a file format but rather a notation. That notation is commonly represented in DER or PEM format.

The DER format is binary, while the PEM format is base64; Therefore, neither the DER nor PEM format are *human-readable*.

The human-readable representation of a certificate is not standardized and has no name; however, you can get a human readable representation of a certificate using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) (and some of its wrappers).

I am not very familiar with node.js; however, taking a quick look at npm (the official node.js package manager) I found many OpenSSL [wrappers](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/openssl).

[wopenssl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wopenssl) seems to have a fairly complete suite for parsing certificates. It allows you to get the issuer, the expiry dates, and so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The function wopenssl.x509.parseCert(cert) gives me the information I need. Thank you!